# Field extension-degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have the following question...

$K\leq E$ a field extension.

When we have that $$[E:K]=1$$ do we conclude that $K=E$??

Or must also something else be satisfied so that $K=E$ ??

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can conclude that $K=E$.
In fact the degree of an extension $K\subseteq E$  is the dimension of $E$ as a $K$-vector space. Hence $E=K$.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you so much!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It means $\;\deg_KE=1\;$ , so

$$\deg_KK=\deg_KE=1\;\;\text{and also}\;\;K\le E$$

from both conditions above it follows from linear algebra that $\;E=K\;$ , so it is always true.

Comment: Nice!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)